How to trace a SAS FCMP Compilation Error?
I get the below after compiling around 70 or 80 inter-connected FCMP functions.  The weird thing is, it doesn't happen at one particular function - it only happens when exiting (quitting) the FCMP procedure, and if I instantiate / quit after every single function, the function on which it occurs will change depending on the order of the functions.  So it doesn't appear to be related to a particular line of code, nor the total number of functions.
How to debug further?  I only see trace options for execution, not compilation.
ERROR: Parsing error generating code.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE FCMP used (Total process time):
      real time           0.10 seconds
      cpu time            0.11 seconds


Can you reproduce the problem with functions that you can post?

I was able to compile in the end by simply sorting the functions alphabetically.  I had previously arranged things such that if f(a) called f(b) then I would call f(b) first.  This avoided the type conversion messages in the log (eg if f(b) returned a char value, f(a) would assume numeric).
I guess that compilation in an 'out of order' sequence forces placeholders which gets around the compilation issue.  It just results in lots of messages like this:
NOTE: Numeric value converted to character.
NOTE: Numeric value converted to character for argument 1 of 'UPCASE' operation.
NOTE: Numeric value converted to character for argument 1 of 'UPCASE' operation.
NOTE: Numeric value converted to character.


Glad you got it sorted.  Would recommend submitting this to tech support.  Sounds bug-ish.

Just curious, will inter-connected macros generate the same question? If there are hundreds macros.
